# BigQuery SQL Geo function that return the coordinates of full address

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I wonder if BigQuery has an SQL Geo function that returns the location coordinates based on the full address.

Comment: did you see [Geography Functions in BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, yes i did but could not locate one.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant to say - there is no such function :o)

Comment: disappointing.
it is a data quality problem. I need to locate the wrong coordinates in the sense that they do not correspond to the address. the easy path would be to recalculate the coordinates.  in the absence of such SQL Geo function how would you approach this problem.

Comment: submit feature request :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the response from BigQuery.

Thanks for feature request!

Geocoding is currently not supported by BigQuery directly, but
thanks for request, we'll consider it for future planning.

The typical solution is to do it outside of BigQuery, 
e.g. in Dataflow job using Google Maps Geocoding API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start
or similar third-party APIs.

For some addresses the Open Street Map can be used for geocoding,
we host it at `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_nodes`.