# Use Geocoding Service in Bigquery UDFs

Tags: google-bigquery, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api, bigquery-udf

I am trying to create a Bigquery UDF function that uses Googles [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#maps_geocoding_reverse-javascript).

It seems we can import external libraries with the [option parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-javascript-libraries) but I feel that I cant use the Geocoding service here.

Following my function approach:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
      functions.returnGeoCode(address STRING)
    RETURNS Array<String>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        alert(latitude);
    } 
}); 
    """
```

which complains because it does not know `google` of course saying `ReferenceError: google is not defined at UDF$1(STRING) line 2, columns 23-24` when I try to use the function.

My ultimate goal is to convert addresses that I have in a Bigquery dataset to lat/longs so I can then create a heatmap in a visualization tool.

Any tips for my approach or something totally different? I saw some suggestions to use some public Bigquery datasets ([openstreetmaps suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60723514/bigquery-sql-geo-function-that-return-the-coordinates-of-full-address)) but I have addresses from Germany and it does not cover that well.

Also Bigquery does not support [the conversion this way](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) it seems.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the feature you need is from [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#maps_geocoding_reverse-javascript), what I could suggest is you can script out everything where you use [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results) (to execute queries) and Geocoding API (to perform Geocoding calculations) in a javascript I suppose. You can perform the calculation of Geocoder separately from the query, afterwards use the returned value from Geocoder on your query using BigQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a self-contained external javascript library, but it would not work with Geocoder service - here the javascript library makes external HTTP calls, which is not allowed for javascript UDF.

I think the appropriate solution is Cloud DataFlow - you can include arbitrary code there, without security and performance restrictions of UDF, read data out of BigQuery table, and write the results back.

If you have a lot of data, and Geocoder service becomes expensive, I think OpenStreetMaps can help - try to resolve data using OSM tables, then resolve the remaining addresses using Geocoder service.